# Visual Studio MVC4 Auto Url Routing for All Url's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, routes

Hello everyone I am working with VS13 MVC4 in localhost, for url routing I want VS will work for all url's automatically as www.sitename.com/about-us but now it is getting underscore (_) not dash (-) how to make a change and get hyphen(-) before every new word in url

Here is the answer I also add it to my question for everyone can see:

```
public class HyphenatedRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString().Replace("-", "_");
        return base.GetHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }

}



public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.Add(
        new Route("{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(
                new { controller = "Default", action = "Index", id = "" }),
                new HyphenatedRouteHandler())
    );    
  }
}
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

If you want pretty url in asp.net mvc then you should go by registering new route for your controller.

- from the application directory open `RouteConfig.cs` in the `App_Start` directory.
- And in the `RegisterRoutes` method of `RouteConfig` class register a new route like this-

  ```
      routes.MapRoute(
          name: "AboutUs",
          url: "sitename/about-us",
          defaults: new { controller = "About_Us", action = "Index" }
      );
  ```

Comment: @J.Electro go with this. I'm mobile at the moment do can't provide links but this is one on the options I was talking about

Comment: Thank you all, I am working on it but couldn't figure out fully, also I would like to ask if I ll do this one by one for my links (as I understood) isn't it better to finish the project then work for it ?

Comment: better but if you use these urls in anywhere in your application then you should change those urls also one by one, i think when you create a controller create a new route for that.

Comment: Thank to god I don't have a lot of pages :) Thanks for help guys :)

Answer (score 1):

The _ will prob be automatically converted to a - in the routing. The other way is to set up the routing yourself

Comment: Is there any detailed link about it because as I said I do not know exactly, learning still about it... Thx